# Bicep modules and loop

Tags: azure-bicep

how I can use loop in modules in Bicep?

I mean like this.

```
module vnet01 'vNet.bicep' = [ for vnet in vnets :  { 
        name: vnet.name
        scope:  virtualNetworkRg
        params: { 
          vnetName: vnet.name
          vnetAddressPrefix: vnet.vnetAddressPrefix
          location: location
        }
      }]
```

I get the error when I run the code

> {'code': 'InvalidTemplate', 'message': "Deployment template validation
> failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/vnet01' at line
> '128' and column '5' is defined multiple times in a template. Please
> see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'.",
> 'additionalInfo': [{'type': 'TemplateViolation', 'info':
> {'lineNumber': 128, 'linePosition': 5, 'path':
> 'properties.template.resources[2]'}}]}

Thank you for your support

Comment: should work, are you sure you dont have duplicated `vnet.name` ?

Answer (score 2):

There was a problem in my code (twice use from vnet.name). Thank you from your support.

Comment: good to hear you solved your issue